# What do “Analyze Notebook" and "Analyze Cells" Do?

Tags: front-end, warning-messages, code-review, coding-style, message-coding

*What does "Analyze Notebook" and "Analyze Cells" do?*

They seem to, at least, point out some coding errors that are already highlighted in a notebook. Do they do anything else?

Is there anything the analysis catches that Mathematica doesn't already auto-highlight/mark?

Is it true that the presence of green check mark implies the code will run without error?

[image: pic]

Comment: A couple examples of suspicious code that are not highlighted: `a -> #&` and `a ~~ b | c ~~ d`.